# Creating multiple columns for a grouped pyspark dataframe

Tags: dataframe, group-by, pyspark

I'm trying to add several new columns to my dataframe (preferably in a for loop), with each new column being the count of certain instances of  `col B`, after grouping by `column A`.

What doesn't work:

```
import functions as f
#the first one will be fine
df_grouped=df.select('A','B').filter(df.B=='a').groupBy('A').count()
df_grouped.show()
+---+-----+
| A |count|
+---+-----+
|859|    4|
|947|    2|
|282|    6|
|699|   24|
|153|   12|

# create the second column:
df_g2=df.select('A','B').filter(df.B=='b').groupBy('A').count() 
df_g2.show()
+---+-----+
| A |count|
+---+-----+
|174|   18|
|153|   20|
|630|    6|
|147|   16|

#I get an error on adding the new column:
df_grouped=df_grouped.withColumn('2nd_count',f.col(df_g2.select('count')))
```

The error:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'

I also tried it without using `f.col`, and with just `df_g2.count`, but I get an error saying "col should be column".

Something that DOES work:

```
df_g1=df.select('A','B').filter(df.B=='a').groupBy('A').count()
df_g2=df.select('A','B').filter(df.B=='b').groupBy('A').count()
df_grouped=df_g1.join(df_g2,['A'])
```

However, I'm going to add up to around 1000 new columns, and having that so many joins seems costly. I wonder if doing joins is inevitable, given that every time I group by `col A`, its order changes in the grouped object (e.g. compare order of `column A` in df_grouped with its order in `df_g2` in above), or there is a better way to do this.

Comment: You get an error while creating `df_g2`?

Comment: No, on adding the count() column from that to df_grouped. I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: Makes sense. You are adding a new column to df_grouped, but without specify the location (or position) of each newly added element. Do not think like python, here data is distributed and you need to specify where to put each element. In the second approach, you tell it: *join elements of df_g2 to elements of df_g1, where they have the same element in A*. So you implicitly are telling it in which position put elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably need is `groupby` and `pivot`. 
Try this:

```
df.groupby('A').pivot('B').agg(F.count('B')).show()
```

Comment: Thanks. pivot does it for all instances of col B, and not just for the certain ones that I'm interested in, but I can probably first filter on col B and then do the grouping and pivoting.

Comment: yes, something like this should work: `df.filter(df.B.isin(['a', 'b', 'c']).groupby('A').pivot('B').agg(F.count('B')).show()`